Unable to filter and upload in Veracode Scan
I’m currently working on uploading artifacts for a Veracode scan using an Azure Classic build pipeline. However, the artifact includes a Code Coverage report, which I don’t want to include in the Veracode scan. I’m having trouble excluding this from the scan using the Veracode task. Could someone guide me on how to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

In the Advanced Scan Settings -> Optional Arguments field, you can use exclude parameter to exclude your code coverage report from Veracode scan.
According to exclude,

Case-sensitive, comma-separated list of module name patterns that represent the names of modules to not scan as top-level modules. The * wildcard matches 0 or more characters. The ? wildcard matches exactly one character. This parameter applies to all folders and files specified for -filepath.

The following example specifies that the scan is of high importance, to exclude code coverage report cobertura-coverage.xml, scan in a sandbox named mysandbox, which Veracode creates if the sandbox does not already exist, and to delete a scan with a status of incomplete, no modules defined, failed, or cancelled:
-criticality high -exclude cobertura-coverage.xml -createsandbox true -sandboxname mysandbox -deleteIncompleteScan 1

See the details from Add Static Analysis to Azure DevOps pipelines.

I did try that by passing like this -exclude $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/Code Coverage Report_70284/* but it didnt help though. The Code Coverage report is generated in the above format and path.

Try to remove $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/ from your command. If it doesn't work, add a variable system.debug and set the value to true, then trigger a new build. Check the debug log to see what's actual command is run in this task and share with me.

This is what i see in the logs.
[2024.08.27 05:37:19.986] Uploading: /home/vsts/work/1/a/Code Coverage Report_70284/com.abc.xyz.def.mapper/ResourceMapper.java.html
[2024.08.27 05:37:19.989] Invoking API https://analysiscenter.veracode.com/api/5.0/uploadlargefile.do?app_id=123456789&filename=ResourceMapper.java.html
[2024.08.27 05:37:19.990] Uploading file: /home/vsts/work/1/a/Code Coverage Report_70284/com.abc.xyz.mapper/ResourceMapper.java.html
[2024.08.27 05:37:19.990] Using 'FixedLengthStreamingMode' with Content-Length=8062

The "Veracode Upload and scan" task actually calls the Veracode API. The command I mentioned is the specific parameters of this task when running the Veracode API. I want to know what the value of exclude passed in is. You should be able to see it in the debug log.

This is what i see in the debug.log for exclude.
##[debug]optargs=-exclude Code Coverage Report_70284

Have a test with these two arguments. -exclude "Code Coverage Report_70284/**"  or -exclude '*/ResourceMapper.java.html' 

The above was an example I gave to exclude for Code Coverage Report. But the Code Coverage report number changes for every build. How to achieve in that case?

“But the Code Coverage report number changes for every build”- Which report number are you talking about? The number after "Code Coverage Report"? I don't have a Veracode license to test. But according to the official doc of Veracode, -exclude Code Coverage Report_70284/** should work if this folder name is fixed. If the number of the folder name is random, you can try  -exclude Code Coverage Report_*/* . This is an extension published by Veracode, which call Veracode API to upload and scan.

If it doesn't work for you, it's suggested that you create a ticket in Veracode Community to confirm further. From Azure DevOps perspective, I would suggest that you don't put your Code Coverage reports in the artifact. If you must put them in the artifact, you can publish two artifacts, one of which does not contain the Code Coverage reports, and upload it to Veracode.

Let me try this pattern -exclude Code Coverage Report_*/* and share the findings here. Thanks for the update though. I will retest my pipeline.

Sure. Happy to help you investigate together.
